# TypeORM OneToMany Relation not Found

Tags: typeorm, typegraphql

this is my first time posting on StackOverflow so hopefully, I am doing this right.

As I started working with typeORM I noticed that ManyToOne relations are working as intended through my resolvers and display the results, while OneToMany relations throw 'relation can't be found' errors.

Things I've tried so far:

Restructuring entities exactly as in TypeOrm documentation

Query using both QueryBuilder and find methods with relations/leftjoin

Wiping and rebuilding Postgresdb

User.ts File

```
@Field(() => [UserComment], { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(() => UserComment, (comment) => comment.user)
  comments: UserComment[];
```

UserComment.ts File

```
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.comments)
  @Field()
  user: User;
```

Test query;

```
return User.findOne(req.session.userId, { relations: ["comments"] });
```

Output

```
"message": "Relation \"comments\" was not found; please check if it is correct and really exists in your entity.",
```

I hope I'm not overlooking something silly. Any suggestions are appreciated.

If it helps, here is to show that many to one side of this relation works as intended:

comment resolver:

```
  async testComments(): Promise<UserComment[]> {
    return await UserComment.find({ relations: ["user"] });
  }
```

result:

```
 "testComments": [
      {
        "body": "This is another test comment.",
        "user": {
          "username": "Admin"
        }
      },
      {
        "body": "Another comment coming up!",
        "user": {
          "username": "Admin"
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a silly mistake related to previous use of mikro-orm (was using OneToMany auto-import from mikro-orm and not typeorm)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using the `@Field` decorator, remove that and try, it should work. It's working in my case.

```
  // remove this @Field(() => [UserComment], { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(() => UserComment, (comment) => comment.user)
  comments: UserComment[]; 

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.comments)
  // remove this @Field()
  user: User;
```

Comment: I used @Field to expose the field for graphql queries, otherwise I get "Cannot query field \"comments\" on type \"User\".", (It comes from type-graphql lib)

Comment: Oh, in that case, I have no clue